# Spring how to handle # in REST URL

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have spring application

which has URL of format

{URL}/locations/USA#CA#92121

I want to get 'USA#CA#92121'  as one parameter in my REST controller .. How can I achieve that?

Currently its only giving "USA" when I use @PathVariable

Comment: save yourself some trouble, and use a different symbol :)

Comment: "safe" chars in URL: `- . _ ~ ! $ & ( ) * + , ; = : @ / ?`

Comment: I wish I could choose that :-)

Comment: whoever made that decision, he is wrong. this is a bad requirement/design.

Comment: refer to the chapter 2.1 and 2.2 of this URL RFC [here](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2) , you might find whats causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL will need to be url encoded. You can use URLEncoder in Java 8 for this.

See [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)

basically

```
String q = "random word £500 bank $";
String url = "http://example.com/query?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(q, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the URL so that it can handle all types of characters including spaces and special characters like #, $ etc..

The best way to do that would be to use an [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)
and then to get back the value that you want, you will need to use the [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

For Example:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

public class EncodeURL {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        string url = "{URL}/locations/USA#CA#92121";
        try {
            string encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("Encoded String: " + encodedString);
            System.out.println("Decoded String: " + URLDecoder.dencode(encodedString, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```